# Does the health bar length relative to the max HP of the monster?

Tags: diablo-iii

Of what I've seen in game, the health bar of monsters can be longer or shorter, depending on the monster you're facing.

So what makes the bar longer or shorter? My guess would be the max HP, but I do think I'm wrong on that. So what does?

Comment: optical illusion maybe? otherwise just based on the physical size of the monster's model

Comment: I mean the one on top of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its max HP, but there's a limit to how long that bar can go.

For example, a zombie with 10hp can have a health bar of 10pixels (or cm, or whatever you want to use as a base of measurement), while a flying molok with 50hp can have a hp bar of 50px.

But if, say a boss monster would have 100k HP, the length of the HP bar would be capped at, say, 200px max.